# Webpack Not Creating CSS Files, issues with style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

It's important to first say that everything was working, but it somehow just broke.

I am trying to get standalone css files and will include them in my index.html file

But the css is still loaded inline in main.bundle.js, but the css is missing from the page.  I've noticed in main.bundle.js I see a lot of "\n"

`padding-right: 15px;\n}\n.btn.content-btn::before {\n  position: absolute;\n`

I know this webpack file is messy but I have been trying different variations for hours.

I am new to wepback so I would appreciate some help.  I am using webpack 5.68.0

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
// const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
// css twice [CONTENTS]
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
    //devtool: 'inline-module-source-map',
  devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        // path: __dirname + '/dist',
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
      minSize: 60000,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 5,
      maxInitialRequests: 3,
      cacheGroups: {
        // styles: {
        //   name: 'styles',
        //   test: /\.s?css$/,
        //   chunks: 'all',
        //   minChunks: 1,
        //   reuseExistingChunk: true,
        //   enforce: true,
        // },
        vendor: {
          test: /node_modules/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'initial',
          enforce: true
        },
        vendorModules: {
          test: /src\/js\/modules/,
          name: 'vendor-modules',
          chunks: 'initial',
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                // use: [
        //   'babel-loader',
        //   'eslint-loader',
        // ]
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
          // {
          //   loader: 'eslint-webpack-plugin',
          //   options: {
          //     quiet: true
          //   }
          // }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
          // {
          //   loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          //   options: {
          //     publicPath: __dirname + '/public',
          //   },
          // },
          // {
          //   loader: 'css-loader',
          //   options: {
          //     importLoaders: 2,
          //     sourceMap: true
          //   }
          // },
          // {
          //   loader: "sass-loader",
          //   options: {
          //     sourceMap: true,
          //     sassOptions: {
          //       indentWidth: 2,
          //       includePaths: ["src/styles"],
          //     },
          //   },
          // },
        ],
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
      //   //test: /\.scss$/,
      //   //test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
      //   exclude: /node_modules/,
      //   use: [
      //     {
      //       loader: 'file-loader',
      //       options: { outputPath: 'css/', name: '[name].min.css'}
      //     },
      //     'style-loader',
      //     {
      //       loader: "sass-loader"
      //     }
      //   ]
      // },
      // {
      //   test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
      //   use: [
      //     // something is making styles show up twice.     I don't want style loader loads twice???
      //     "style-loader", // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
      //     "css-loader",      // Translates CSS into CommonJS
      //     {
      //       loader: 'sass-loader',
      //       options: {
      //         sourceMap: true
      //       }
      //     },          // Compiles Sass to CSS
      //   ],
      // },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
      }
      // {
      //   test: /\.svg$/,
      //   use: [
      //     {
      //       loader: 'svg-url-loader',
      //       options: {
      //         limit: 10000,
      //       },
      //     },
      //   ],
      // },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', ".ts"],
    fallback: {
      "fs": false,
      "os": false,
      "tls": false,
      "net": false,
      "path": false,
      "zlib": false,
      "http": false,
      "https": false,
      "browser": false,
      "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      "buffer": require.resolve("buffer"),
      "crypto": false,
      "crypto-browserify": require.resolve('crypto-browserify'), //if you want to use this module also don't forget npm i crypto-browserify
    }
    },

  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: [
      'learntoearn.dev',
    ],
    historyApiFallback: true,
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
  },
    plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin( // split css into files
      {
        // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
        // both options are optional
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
      }
    ),
    //new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    new ESLintPlugin(),
    new Dotenv(),
    new ESLintPlugin({
      quiet: true,
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
    }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + '/public/index.html',
      // template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: false // BROKE AGAIN FOR SOME REASON, SO SETTING TO TRUE
      //inject: 'body' // causing styles to be loaded twice!
    })
    ]
};
```

Comment: `everything was working, but it somehow just broke` Do you have any history with git, etc? What changed and then "just broke"?

Comment: I have tried going back in git without any luck.  Another developer is able to run without these problems.  I'm starting to think my local mac with the m1 chip is causing issues although I have restarted.


What I really want to do is create .css files from the scss files instead of doing things inline.

I think the chunks and the splitting is messing things up perhaps

    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',

Comment: If your coworker can run it, compare line by line, reinstall your deps, check versions etc. I highly doubt your chip is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had several issues for anyone who has this problem.

Delete node modules.

Clear yarn/npm cache.

Install everything again.

in your wepback file include this

```
      {
        //test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        test: /\.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

in plugins, all you need is this

```
    plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(), // split css into files
```

Webpack then created a main.css file and included it in index.html